# Reset page number for group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to reset page number for every group in MS Reporting services. I know about such possibility in MS Reporting Services 2008 R2, but I haven't possibility to uprade it.

Also, I know about this [MSDN post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrishays/archive/2006/01/05/resetpagenumberongroup.aspx). However, a problem here exists. When I switch pages forward all seems ok, but when back page numbering works wrong. I have page numbers like this:

> 1, 0, -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I can answer this question. 
The idea of algorithm is to set the page number once, save it to array and then when we flip pages back, not to count it from beginning, but take page number from global page array.
This idea works perfectly and here some code how to set this solution up

```
Shared offset as Integer
Shared currentgroup as Object
Shared currentPage as Integer
Shared Dim pagesArray() As Integer

Public Function GetGroupPageNumber(group as Object, pagenumber as Integer, totalpages as Integer) as Object
If Not (group = currentgroup)
offset = pagenumber - 1
currentgroup = group
End If
If (pagesArray Is Nothing) Then
ReDim Preserve pagesArray(totalpages)
End If
If (CountNumberOfElementsInArray(pagesArray) < totalpages)
pagesArray(pagenumber - 1) = pagenumber - offset
End If
Return pagesArray(pagenumber - 1)
End Function

Public Function CountNumberOfElementsInArray(array() As Integer) as Integer
Dim counter as Integer
Dim i As Integer
counter = 0
For i = 0 To array.Length - 1
If (array(i) <> 0)
counter = counter + 1
End If
Next i
Return counter
End Function
```

Detail information you can find at my blog 
[Reset page number in ms reporting services](http://alexkuznetsov.wordpress.com/2013/05/06/reset-page-number-in-ms-reporting-services/)